# Scroll in GridView : ItemPanelTemplate

Tags: gridview, panel, winrt-xaml

I have a problem in my [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview), in a Windows Store App project. There's no WrapPanel in WinRT so I use a custom panel I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24141/WrapPanel-for-Silverlight-2-0). But when I use this custom panel as ItemsPanelTemplate in my GridView, the horizontal scroll of the GridView doesn't work anymore. If the ItemsPanelTemplate  is a StackPanel, the scroll works properly.

Does the custom panel should implement an interface to have a better behaviour, like [IScrollSnapPointsInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.iscrollsnappointsinfo) ? I tried it but I don't really know how it works.

**GridView**

```
<GridView x:Name="FullGrid"  Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContactSource.View}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    IsSwipeEnabled="true"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    Padding="116,10,40,10"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource contactTemplate}"
    SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"
    ItemClick="NavigateToContact">

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource letterTemplate}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using this [custom panel](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT/blob/master/Q42.WinRT/Controls/WrapPanel.cs).